# Error in gradle build

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle

Gradle build finishes with one error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v18\values-v18.xml: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1
```

What is the solution?

Comment: which version of gradle are you running?

Comment: and paste your `build.gradle` file

Comment: `app:mergeDebugResources`... One of your XML files is bad

Comment: post the content of `values-v18.xml` in your question so we can help you troubleshoot it

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you have an issue with format XML in

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v18\values-v18.xml

Try to reach that file and check what is the issue .. may be unescaped character or other format issue.

Then try to clean and build project again

Comment: Except that file, in particular, is auto-generated, so it can't be edited

Comment: @cricket_007 yes ... but it will be helpful to know the issue .. then fixing it is the next step, right ?